# Creating runable jar file Intellij with mysql connector in Java JDBC

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, jar, mysql-connector

I'm having an issue with creating a runable jar file that includes mysql connector library.

So my IDE is IntelliJ and I have successfully imported mysql connector to my library so my application works fine with sql in IntelliJ.

But when I create a artifact and export my application to a jar file, I got the error:
        `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:`

In my java code I use the following code. And this works perfectly fine in IntelliJ, but not when I run it in my terminal

```
String myDriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://website.com/mydatabase_db";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "myuser", "myPassword");
```

I try to run the code in my terminal with:
`java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar -jar application.jar`

Comment: java -jar ignores the -cp parameter. You can: build a "fatJAR", add the msql.jar to the classpath in you jar's manifest, or move mysql.jar to [jvm]/lib/ext

Comment: can I build a fatJAR in IntelliJ?

Comment: I usually use maven based projects. Works in any IDE. Start here: https://mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/